# Editing PostgreSQL/PostGIS table via join in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a standard PostgreSQL/PostGIS table and another table which stores a geometry. They both already have a relationship with ondelete/onupdate cascade.

I make a PostGIS connection in QGIS 2.18, I add both to the layers, I can access both of their attribute tables. I go to Project/Project Properties and set the relation.

I open the geom table and join the table. I then open the attribute table in edit mode, those columns from the 'geom table' can be edited, however I cannot edit those columns which are joined from the other table.

Where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Why join in QGIS when you have PostgreSQL as the back-end? You can create views that are editable in QGIS, as I think you're already on the path to doing using ondelete/onupdate rules...

Comment: I made a view, but I have the same problem, I need to allow others edit the polygon attributes, so I was trying to keep it in QGIS to keep it simple. At this stage any solution is acceptable.

Comment: What about the data maintenance workflow requires the spatial data? Is it an interactive selection that points the user to the geometry that then needs updating in the related table? Short version- why does QGIS need to be a part of the editing workflow of non-spatial data in this case?

Comment: Short answer: The user needs to select a polygon and update related data, data which is related/joined but stored in another table (one without any geometry). Longer answer: the data in the related table is visualised in the polygon's (geom's) symbology, the only way for the users to check their data is to see the related spatial data.